# No wifi adapter found, even after installing RTL8821ce drivers

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

I've already asked this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254127/how-to-fix-no-wifi-adapter-found). I tried everything suggested there and I still can't connect to WiFi wirelessly. I've reinstalled the [tomaspinho/rtl8821ce](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) about 3 times now, I've also tried installing the rtl8821ce-dkms package and for some reason nothing works. I still can't connect to WiFi because I always get "No WiFi Adapter Found". My Ubuntu version is 20.04 and my laptop is an asus TUF FX505dt. I have almost no experience with Linux so any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-config.c:656 kmod_config_parse: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf line 1: ignoring bad line starting with 'df'
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3041]
    Kernel modules: 8821ce, rtl8821ce
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Picasso [1043:18f1]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT 2:

`grep rtl /etc/modprobe.d/*` doesn't output anything

output of `dmesg | grep rtl`:

```
[    3.513274] rtl8821ce 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.551035] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 402 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1681 rtw_os_ndev_register+0x6c/0x169 [8821ce]
[    3.725353] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 402 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3141 rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xb6/0xde [8821ce]
[    3.870584] proc_dir_entry 'net/rtl8821ce' already registered
[    3.870619] Modules linked in: rtl8821ce(OE+) snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event nvidia(PO) amdgpu(+) snd_rawmidi ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_seq amd_iommu_v2 8821ce(OE) gpu_sched ttm asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi input_leds snd_seq_device serio_raw snd_timer sparse_keymap hid_multitouch wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper ipmi_devintf snd ipmi_msghandler i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops k10temp syscopyarea sysfillrect cfg80211(OE) sysimgblt compat(OE) soundcore asus_wireless mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 nvme nvme_core r8169 realtek wmi video i2c_hid hid
[    3.870835]  rtw_drv_proc_init+0x3b/0xc8 [rtl8821ce]
[    3.870872]  rtw_drv_entry+0x28/0x1000 [rtl8821ce]
[    3.871039] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 402 at /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/os_dep/linux/rtw_proc.c:273 rtw_drv_proc_init+0x54/0xc8 [rtl8821ce]
[    3.871039] Modules linked in: rtl8821ce(OE+) snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi crct10dif_pclmul snd_seq_midi_event nvidia(PO) amdgpu(+) snd_rawmidi ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper snd_seq amd_iommu_v2 8821ce(OE) gpu_sched ttm asus_nb_wmi asus_wmi input_leds snd_seq_device serio_raw snd_timer sparse_keymap hid_multitouch wmi_bmof drm_kms_helper ipmi_devintf snd ipmi_msghandler i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops k10temp syscopyarea sysfillrect cfg80211(OE) sysimgblt compat(OE) soundcore asus_wireless mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid_generic crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 nvme nvme_core r8169 realtek wmi video i2c_hid hid
[    3.871119] RIP: 0010:rtw_drv_proc_init+0x54/0xc8 [rtl8821ce]
[    3.871163]  rtw_drv_entry+0x28/0x1000 [rtl8821ce]
[    3.871238] Error: Driver 'rtl8821ce' is already registered, aborting...
```

output of `dkms status`:

```
rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1, 5.4.0-39-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8821ce, v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.4.0-39-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: @Pilot6 already did that

Comment: You have problems in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf`. Delete this file.  And also pleas post output of commands: `grep rtl /etc/modprobe.d/*` and `dmesg | grep rtl` and `dkms status`

Comment: @Pilot6 I edited the question with all the outputs I got. I also deleted blacklist-ideapad.conf and I still have the same problem.

Comment: You installed some wireless backports package, possibly iwlwifi and that will need to be removed

Comment: @Jeremy31 That's actually what fixed it for me. The only thing I needed to do was uninstall that package and everything was fixed

Answer (score 0):

The driver is crashing. I suggest removing all you installed and using another driver.

Uninstall the `8821ce` driver from https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

by running `sudo make unistall` from the directory where the driver is located. then run:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8821ce-dkms
sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 --all
sudo apt install git
git clone -b rtw88 https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Then reboot.